# Which word order is the correct one？

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

> 1. That is the book I don't want to be read to **out of.**
> 2. That is the book I don't want to be read **out of** to.

(I made those two sentences from a interesting artificial construction that I encountered,
“What did you bring the book I didn’t want to be read to out of up for?")

Which one is the correct word order?

Comment: Asking to check text for errors is off-topic on this site. Have you done any research? If so, can you update your question to explain which one you favour and why, and where your doubts lie? That might make it acceptable. If you can't be bothered researching, there are proofreading sites where you can pay to get your work checked professionally.

Comment: When you say "…from a(n) interesting artificial construction that I encountered…" does that mean AI (ChatGPT or Gemini)? I'm asking because I didn't think Large Language Models could make grammatical errors like that. That string of *five prepositions* is close to absurdity. Are you sure you copied it correctly? As for your two sentences, none of them are idiomatic or sound natural, but at least you reduced the number of prepositions at the end!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - This is an example sentence sometimes used in the context of 'whether or not it's acceptable to end a sentence with a preposition' - obviously, it's an extreme example!

Comment: ForOU  - Your second sentence doesn't work because you have split up the phrasal verb _read to_.

Comment: After reading @Kate's observation, my advice is not to imitate that absurd example you saw. It probably works better in speech because we can use intonation and pauses to clarify, but in an exam it would be marked wrong, not for ending  in a preposition, which is perfectly acceptable, but because there are five of them! P.S Not my downvote. Users should ask for clarification and not be so quick to demonise. **If you add the source**, I'm sure users will start upvoting instead.

Comment: [The sentence with 5 prepositions](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/57gji1/what_did_you_bring_that_book_that_i_dont_want_to/) (2016)

Comment: [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=read+to+out+of&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) brings up various versions quoted in books on grammar.